# Custom Field created in add_meta_boxes reappearing itself again in the default Custom Metabox

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, metabox, child-theme

I succeed in creating a metabox with custom field inside, and I restrict it to appear in a custom post type.

```
//define metabox
function product_info_en() {
    add_meta_box( 'english_info', 'English Info', 'english_product_name_callback', array('product'), 'normal', 'high' );
}

//add to hook
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_info_en' );
```

The code to display it in the product page:

```
// display in add product admin page
function english_product_name_callback( $post ) {
    //ob_start();
    $content = esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_desc_en', true ) );

        //here goes the custom field
        echo '<fieldset><div><label><b>English Product Name:</b></label><br/>';
        echo '<input id="product_name_en" type="text" name="product_name_en" style="width:100%; margin:10px 0px"';
        echo ' value="';
        echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_desc_en', true ) );
        echo '"></div></fieldset>';

        //here goes the wp_editor
        echo '<fieldset><div><label><b>English Product Content Info:</b></label><div><br/>';
        echo '<div>';
        wp_editor($content, 'product_desc_en', array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_rows' => 10
            )
            );
        echo '</div></fieldset>';
}
```

Here goes the code that do the saving job:

```
//save
function enginfo_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        $post_id = $parent_id;
    }
    $fields = [
        'product_name_en',
    ];
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field] ) );
        }
     }
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'product_desc_en', wp_kses_post( $_POST['product_desc_en'] ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'enginfo_save_meta_box' );
```

However, the custom created field that supposed to be going only into the newly created metabox, will always show up in the default "custom field". And this happens to all post type.
As shown below, What could possibly be the issue here?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending your metakey with an underscore `_` makes it private and prevents the data from showing up in the default metabox.

So instead of this,

```
update_post_meta( $post_id,'product_desc_en', wp_kses_post( $_POST['product_desc_en'] ) );
```

do this,

```
update_post_meta( $post_id,'_product_desc_en', wp_kses_post( $_POST['product_desc_en'] ) );
```

and your custom meta shouldn't show up in the default metabox.

*P.s. And of course, when using `get_post_meta()`, you'll need to use the underscored metakey to fetch the data.*

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#hidden-custom-fields

**As a side note**

`add_meta_boxes` and `save_post` are general hooks, which means your callbacks are fired whenever the actions run. So you're codes run in cases when they're not strictly required, e.g. when saving a post of some other type. If you want, you can use post type specific hooks (`add_meta_boxes_product` and `save_post_product`) to limit your code only to the required cases.

Also, you can add an extra level of (healthy) paranoia to your code with nonces and capability checking to make sure that the meta data is saved only when intended.

To add a hidden nonce field to your metabox,

```
function english_product_name_callback( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( 'my_save_action_' . $post->ID, 'my_save_action_' . $post->ID );

  // your code
}
```

Nonce and capability check when saving,

```
function enginfo_save_meta_box( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
    return;
  }
  $nonce = ! empty( $_POST['my_save_action_' . $post_id] ) ?  $_POST['my_save_action_' . $post_id]: '';
  if ( ! $nonce || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my_save_action_' . $post_id ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // your code  
}
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'enginfo_save_meta_box', 10, 3 );
```